# Make link/alias to another directory in public folder ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alias, putty

I am trying to create a link on public/virt folder to a directory ../../../../testdir with name pipelines

for that I have created virt directory using mkdir but I am not able to create this alias/link.

how can it be done using command in putty?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have permission to write to the directory you want the symlink to be located in.

Also, make sure that the relative path you want to link to exists. If it does not, the link will still be created but you may end up somewhere you didn't intend to jump to.

Also, since virt is the name of the symlink you want to create, you did not need to make it with mkdir. "virt" will be the name of the symlink file created by `ln`

To make a symbolic link named /public/virt that points to the testdir directory four levels up from the current working directory:

`ln -s ../../../../testdir public/virt`